# Cayley hamilton theorem for diagonal matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

```
a 0 0
0 b 0
0 0 0
```

Let A be this matrix.

Characteristic equation of this matrix is (x^2) - (a+b).x + a.b = 0.

but A does'nt satisfy this equation. What am I missing?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $x(x^2 - (a+b)x +ab) = 0$.

Comment: three. it will be x.(x-a)(x-b)=0. dividing it by x gives (x-a)(x-b)=0

Answer (score 1):

This is not the characteristic polynomial. Actually
$$\chi_A(x)=-(x^3-(a+b)x^2+abx).$$

Comment: correct. but cant I divide it by x and equate to zero.

Comment: You forget the ring of $3\times3$ matrices  has zero divisors . You can't simplify: $A^3-(a+b)A^2+ab A=0$, yet  $A^2-(a+b)A+ab I\neq 0$ and $A\neq 0$.

Comment: thanks a lot. bear with me a little more. I look at it as the characteristic polynomial can be equated to zero and x can be cancelled. but remaining polynomial is not characteristic polynomial and given matrix doesnt have to satisfy the remaining equation. correct??

Comment: The matrix, no. Never forget matrices do not behave exactly as numbers. You just obtain the $3$ eigenvalues, which you already know.